# Azeotropic Distillation - Am I interpreting this VLE diagram correctly?

Tags: equilibrium, distillation

I've been looking at ways to re-concentrate a formic acid-water binary mixture with the VLE diagram below.

[image]

Am I correct in saying that to concentrate a solution of say , 40% formic acid by weight I could (excluding all recycle streams for simplicity) implement a distillation column at 1 bar to produce a distillate at the azeotrope (78%) and then pass this distillate into a second column operating at 0.1 bar to distill further to 95%?

Aditionally, would operating the 1bar column for a distillate of say only 70% (past the 0.1 bar azeotrope) then performing the remaining concentration in the low pressure column result in any significant energy savings due to less steam required at the lower pressure?

Lastly, if I was to START with a solution of 85% formic acid, already beyond both azeotropes, I could just perform simple distillation in a single column at either pressure point to obtain the 95% product?